MySQL Authentication Plugin Issues on macOS
I’m working on a blog project using Python and Flask, and I’m using the MySQL database from XAMPP for user registration. The project worked perfectly on my Windows machine, but after switching to macOS, I’ve been encountering various issues with the registration process. I’ve managed to resolve most of the issues, but I’m still struggling with one particular error. I’ve been working on this for a week now and could use some help.
Error Details:
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'mysql_native_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/9.0.1/lib/plugin/mysql_native_password.so, 0x0002): tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/9.0.1/lib/plugin/mysql_native_password.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/9.0.1/lib/plugin/mysql_native_password.so' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/9.0.1/lib/plugin/mysql_native_password.so' (no such file)")
enter image description here
Context:
•   The application is running on macOS using XAMPP.
•   The database is configured correctly, and I can connect to it using other tools.
•   I’ve tried various solutions like asking chatgpt or searching on google

Has anyone encountered this issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance for your help!


xampp switched over to mariadb instead of mysql years ago. If your app was designed to work with mariadb, then a migration to mysql will result in several surprises. 2) mysql 9.0 is an experimental version. Do not use it if you are not familiar with mysql.


Related: https://gist.github.com/syahzul/d760e946976022ad6944c8f2e7813750

You need to install mysql@8.4 or mysql-client@8.4 on MacOS. Because native authentication plugin was removed from mysql 9.0
Run the command line below to uninstall mysql@9.0.1

brew uninstall mysql

Run the command lines below to install mysql@8.4

brew install mysql@8.4
ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@8.4 /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql
If you need to have mysql first in your PATH, run:
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc


"You need to install mysql@8.4" - why exactly? Please add some explanation to oyur answer such that others can learn from it

@NicoHaase Because native authentication plugin was removed from mysql 9.0.

Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. Also, why not change the application such that it uses another plugin, as suggested in the other answer?

Because some people are using the client to connect to non-9.0 databases and never asked to upgrade the brew package to something incompatible, and just pinning to a compatible brew package is a lot easier than fooling with auth plugins.

I followed all these steps and get the error
mysql_secure_installation
Securing the MySQL server deployment.
Enter password for user root:
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)
how can I resolve this?

Wonderful! It worked! The maintainers of the brew package should probably update the defaults.

Yeah, the default is v9. btw, I installed just the client - brew install mysql-client@8.4. The server will run on docker...

I had to run brew link mysql@8.4 --force to make mysql available system wide. Homebrew and Mysql were installed in different locations.

Downgrading to an insecure solution is not a good idea. There are good reasons for the old authentication hashing algorithm to be abandoned as can be found here.
A better solution is to upgrade the hashing algorithm to a more secure one. If setting up a database this should happen automatically. If upgrading from an earlier version there is a nice write-up here that explains how to temporarily disable authentication to allow manual upgrades of the password hashing algorithm.
Reproduction of the steps in the link:

Disable the Grant Tables:
Edit the MySQL configuration file, typically located at /etc/my.cnf.
Add the following line under the [mysqld] section to disable the grant tables:
 [mysqld]
 skip-grant-tables


Restart MySQL

Connect to MySQL as the root user:
mysql -u root

Refresh the privileges:
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Check for users using the mysql_native_password plugin:
SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user WHERE plugin = 'mysql_native_password';


Update the user(s) to use the caching_sha2_password plugin, e.g.:
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'new_password';


Re-enable Grant Tables:
After updating, remove or comment out the skip-grant-tables line from the MySQL configuration file.

Restart MySQL to apply the changes



Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)
every time I run the mysql command this error comes up. any ideas why?

Mysql's native authentication plugin was removed from mysql 9.0. You need to change the authentication plugin used for the users to one of the supported ones or downgrade mysql from the experimental 9.0 to a production 8.4 or 8.0 version.

How do I do this? What should I write in the console? Sorry im just a beginner

In this case I suggest you revert back to a current production version. Uninstall mysql 9.0, install a current production version and restore your backup there.

Although, you may fare better if you kept using mariadb and avoid migration to mysql. As I wrote in my comment directly to your question, migration from mariadb to mysql will come with surprises, which you can avoid by keep using mariadb.

sorry in my course we are using mysql. so how can I solve that problem right now ?

Go back to v8.4 or v8.0

what should I do ?Do I need to download a different version of XAMPP, or is there something else I need to do?

Xampp comes with mariadb, not with mysql. Perhaps you have both installed.

okey so what should I do for solve this problem ? how can I go back to v8.4 ?

First verify that xampp's mariadb is around. If so, ise that instead of mysql 9.0. If it is not there, then downgrade mysql 8.0 or 8.4

Adding a solution specific to my situation.  Installed MySQL by way of MAMP (cause it's 'easy').  Needed workbench specifically for the ERD generation.  Workbench couldn't connect to local mysql installed by mamp; other clients could connect.
MySQL installed by MAMP creates a root user using mysql_native_password plugin which is not supported anymore in MySQL 8.4.
Followed instructions here to change PWD storage for that same root user to sha2 cache:
https://php.watch/articles/fix-php-mysql-84-mysql_native_password-not-loaded
Relevant commands are:

Check that it is in fact native password problem:
SELECT user, host, plugin from mysql.user WHERE plugin='mysql_native_password';

Change the user(s) to remove the need for native password plugin:
ALTER USER 'USERNAME'@'HOST' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'NEW_PASSWORD';



MySQL includes mysql_native_password plugin which implements Native Pluggable Authentication
This plugin is deprecated since v8.0 and it's disabled by default in mysql@8.4 but removed as of mysql@9.0
To fix this issue:

Install mysql@8.4
brew install mysql@8.4

Start the server
brew services start mysql@8.4

Enable mysql_native_password in the configuration file


In my case config path is : /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf
sudo nano /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf

Your final file configuration should look like this:
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
mysql_native_password=ON                # Add this line <----
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1

